# R StackExchange package

Tags: discussion, r

Based on a conversation that started [in the chat room](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170/stats) (and [some analysis that Colin did on voting patterns](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314/vote-early-vote-often/317#317)), I have posted the shell of an R StackExchange package here: http://code.google.com/p/overflowr/.  It can currently pull a list of tags, users, questions, etc. from any StackExchange site, but it needs a lot of work before it could be released.  The goal of the package is to make the cc-wiki text readily available for analysis.

Three of the moderators will be working on it.  Happy to invite others who have interest.  Otherwise, feel free to post your requests, use cases, etc. here or on the google code page.

Comment: good initiative !

Answer (score 4):

Hello Shane,

This is a great idea. I am wondering how can I contribute to it. I will be glad to help.